# Is a subscription payment model usable with Apple Pay?

Tags: ios, applepay

Can I create subscription payment model with Apple Pay? I see a lot of examples with a single transaction. But what about subscriptions? For example, each month bill $10 to the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Apple Pay for subscriptions, provided you comply with the guidelines Apple provides:

> Apps using Apple Pay to offer recurring payments must, at a minimum, disclose:
>
> - The length of the renewal term and the fact that it will continue until canceled.
> - What will be provided during each period.
> - The charges that will be billed to the customer. And
> - How to cancel.

The guidelines are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#apple-pay).

Comment: This is great! But how can I use it? I mean, maybe some code examples or tutorials. Because I don't see any:( Even in official documentation.

Comment: It works exactly like a normal Apple Pay payment - is that what you were looking for? Guides on using Apple Pay regularly? If you'd like to know about how to actually take the tokens you get from Apple Pay and use them to make a recurring payment I'd recommend talking to the payment processor you plan to use (Stripe, Braintree, etc)

Comment: So looks like Apple Pay is just service which will send my payment card's data to another service which will make money charge. Right? So I must setup regularly payment system on Stripe or another service.

Comment: Yes, you should take a look at existing payment processors like Stripe or Braintree. They should have specific information about Apple Pay - for example, https://stripe.com/apple-pay

Comment: I am trying to find some sample integration of a subscription model using Apple Pay but with no luck. Were you able to find some resources?

Comment: Do we need to have a payment processor like Stripe, or we can just use apple pay ?

Comment: For the previous comments who couldn't find a solution. You need to use a PaymentSheet